# In Label Text starts after some pixels Ios

Tags: ios, swift

if i am embeding view controller in Navigation controller then Label Text Start after some pixels. If i remove navigation controller then text start from beginning in label. whats the reason behind that and how to solve this problem?

[In this image it's not embedded in navigation controller and textview text start with top.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TA3H.png)

[In this image it's embedded in navigation controller and textview text start with middle of textview.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxNf5.png)

Comment: share some code please

Comment: are you talking about y-coordinates?

Comment: Please share your screenshot what you are expecting.

Comment: Please share screenshot of your controllers.

Answer (score 0):

see below image and uncheck constrain to margin.

[image: that]